# Why is critical decay important?

Tags: differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

When I am studying some paper dealing with dispersive PDE(e.g. Wave, Schrödinger and Klein-Gordon equations), the potential $\frac {1}{|x|^2}$ which is called critical decay (or inverse square potential) is lots of handled.

They also consider Morrey-Campanato or Fefferman-Phong class to deal with that potential since it is contained those class.

The questions are here. Why is it called 'critical' and important or meaningful?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this particular case, but usually the word "critical" is used for parametric problems in the situation when life is nice and easy for, say, $x<x_0$ and the standard theorems of the theory fail or seem completely out of reach for $x>x_0$. Then $x_0$ is declared "critical" and, for the lack of better ideas, people spend time on trying to figure out what happens at $x=x_0$. I'm more familiar with this in the context of evolution PDE with dissipation (where everything is nice when the dissipative term is strong enough and we have no idea what to do if it isn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Critical" in the context of the Schrödinger equation (which seems to be what the OP is after) refers to the number of bound states confined by the potential. The Schrödinger equation with potential $-C|x|^{-2+\epsilon}$ and $C>0$ has a discrete spectrum for $E<0$, with finitely many eigenvalues
if $\epsilon < 0$ and infinitely many if $\epsilon > 0$. Hence inverse square decay is the critical threshold for
the existence of infinitely many bound states. For $\epsilon=0$ whether there are finitely or infinitely many discrete eigenvalues depends on the prefactor $C$.

This basically follows from [Kneser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(differential_equations)), which also gives $C=1/4$ as the critical prefactor.

Comment: How can I check that finitely or infinitely many eigenvalues ?

Comment: isn't that what Kneser's theorem tells you?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will try to understand what it talks to me.